# How to remove text between tags in php?

Tags: php, regex, string

Despite using PHP for years, I've never really learnt how to use expressions to truncate strings properly... which is now biting me in the backside!

Can anyone provide me with some help truncating this? I need to chop out the text portion from the url, turning

```
<a href="link.html">text</a>
```

into

```
<a href="link.html"></a>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $str)
```

Comment: While this works, you generally don't want to parse HTML with regexes. Karim's answer might be preferable.

Answer (score 13):

Using [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
// example of how to modify anchor innerText
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

//set innerText to null for each anchor
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    $e->innerText = null;
}

// dump contents
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: No offense, but this answer is 8 years old, and no one has actually noticed that this answer is incorrect and does not work. The foreach loop has no effect when simply echoing the `$html`. Can't believe this got so many up votes and no one has actually tested it.

Answer (score 8):

What about something like this, considering you might want to re-use it with other `href`s :

```
$str = '<a href="link.html">text</a>';
$result = preg_replace('#(<a[^>]*>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $str);
var_dump($result);
```

Which will get you :

```
string '<a href="link.html"></a>' (length=24)
```

*(I'm considering you made a typo in the OP ? )*

If you don't need to match any other href, you could use something like :

```
$str = '<a href="link.html">text</a>';
$result = preg_replace('#(<a href="link.html">).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $str);
var_dump($result);
```

Which will also get you :

```
string '<a href="link.html"></a>' (length=24)
```

As a sidenote : for more complex HTML, don't try to use regular expressions : they work fine for this kind of simple situation, but for a real-life HTML portion, they don't really help, in general : HTML is not quite "regular" "enough" to be parsed by regexes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use substring in combination with stringpos, eventhough this is not
a very nice approach.

Check: [PHP Manual - String functions](http://www.php.net/manual/ref.strings.php)

Another way would be to write a regular expression to match your criteria.
But in order to get your problem solved quickly the string functions will do...

EDIT: I underestimated the audience. ;) Go ahead with the regexes... ^^

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to capture the tags themselves.  Just target the text between the tags and replace it with an empty string.  Super simple.

[Demo of both techniques](https://3v4l.org/nusfL)

Code:

```
$string = '<a href="link.html">text</a>';
echo preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>\K[^<]*/', '', $string);
// the opening tag--^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^-match everything before the end tag
//                          ^^-restart fullstring match
```

Output:

```
<a href="link.html"></a>
```

Or in fringe cases when the link text contains a `<`, use this:  `~<a[^>]*>\K.*?(?=</a>)~`

This avoids the expense of capture groups using a lazy quantifier, the fullstring restarting `\K` and a "lookahead".

---

Older & wiser:

If you are parsing valid html, you should use a dom parser for stability/accuracy.  Regex is DOM-ignorant, so if there is a tag attribute  value containing a `>`, my snippet will fail.

As a narrowly suited domdocument solution to offer some context:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // 2nd params to remove DOCTYPE);
$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')[0]->nodeValue = '';
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score -2):

Only use `strip_tags()`, that would get rid of the tags and left only the desired text between them

Comment: This is literally the exact opposite of what MrFidge is wanting to do. He wants to remove the text between the tags but keep the tags.