# Remove HTML tags and inner text from string

Tags: php, html

I've been using `strip_tags` to remove HTML tags from string. However, this method still keeps those inner text.

How could I remove both tags and inner text from string?

For example:

```
Hello World <a href="/world">Remove me please!</a>, hello my friends.

//expected result

Hello world, hello my friends.
```

Comment: Could you give an example? Input and desired output.

Comment: Have you considered [`DomDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)? Please post an example of HTML that you want to parse.

Comment: What else will be left? I guess you need to use a DOM parser to extra the parts you really want.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361878/how-to-remove-text-between-tags-in-php

Comment: $str = "He<test>fdgdfgdfg</test>llo";
echo preg_replace('#<.*?>.*?</.*?>#', '', $str);
This is what you want.

Comment: I've read those questions. And actually it doesn't completely answer my questions. Could anybody give an explicitly method. please?

Comment: @Leo Pflug: This could be a good answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from a comment of the PHP documentation for `strip_tags()`

```
<?php 
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
    if($invert == FALSE) { 
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    } 
    else { 
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
  } 
  elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
  } 
  return $text; 
} 
?>
```

All credit to http://www.php.net/strip_tags#86964